# Elastiquent The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I'm using Elastiqent to use from ElasticSearch, every thing is ok, and i have indexed two tables (`resources`,`courses`), and then i have a search form that user type something and choose the query type, resources, and columns of selected resources, then i used from this form data and run the selected query against selected resource for selected fields to find the aimed text. On the mapping of `resources` i have fields with type of `string` and `date-time`, but on mapping of `courses i have integer, text, time, date-time, and string`. when user type some string like `abc` i can get result from `resources` but can't get from `courses` may be due to the integer fields, but if i change that text to an integer value like `1` or any other numbers its ok. I have also used from `ignore_malformed` but no things changed, for searching `abc` give the following error:

`The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

Comment: if you hide those foreign keys?

Comment: @Daenu when i hide those fields, it's ok, but one another problem occur now i want to search for an id of those fields no result come.

Comment: Is this a real case that visitors are searching for id's?

Comment: @Daenu Yeah it is required by visitors for example the use from a dropdown that has the main name of those ids and for example they select a curriculum to search for all the courses that is belonged to the selected curriculum